# Wikitude geolocation not updating poi markers wikitude examples

Tags: javascript, android, geolocation, wikitude

I'm trying to understand the wikitude examples. When I run the example app on my phone, and try one of the POI examples, it loads the poi's into the camera view. However, they always stay relative to me. As I walk around, I can never walk past one, and it appears to always be say 5m away from me. How does one update the wikitide examples so that it shows an absolute geolocation that you can walk around and explore? This seems really simple, but none of the examples online seem relevant to answering this. I have extensively searched the wikitude example docs.

Here is an excerpt from the bottom of the poiatlocation.js file in the architect view -

should I be looking at the js file in the architect world, or in the java code?

```
locationChanged: function locationChangedFn(lat, lon, alt, acc) {

    // request data if not already present
    if (!World.initiallyLoadedData) {
        var poiData = {
            "id": 1,
            "longitude": (lon + (Math.random() / 5 - 0.1)),
            "latitude": (lat + (Math.random() / 5 - 0.1)),
            "altitude": 100.0
        };

        World.loadPoisFromJsonData(poiData);
        World.initiallyLoadedData = true;
    }
},
```

};

/* forward locationChanges to custom function */
AR.context.onLocationChanged = World.locationChanged;

Answer (score 1):

The provided sample implementation creates dummy poi data in the user's vicinity on first location update. 
The POIs may be some km away from the user, you can use "lon + 0.001" and "lat  + 0.001" to create a closer ones.
Also note, that GPS and Network positioning are usually not very accurate and the sample application uses a very basic "Location Strategy" on Android and the default Location Strategy on iOS - So don't expect in-house movements to cause POI-location changes.

Once you try it outdoors with POIs nearby you will notice the location change effect.

Kind regards

PS.:
In case you want to use a more accurate Location Strategy, please have a look at 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html
and overwrite the setLocation implementation of the ARchitectView.
Note: Every architectView.setLocation() in the native environment will also cause a "AR.context.onLocationChanged"-JS-function call.

Comment: My architectView.setLocation() is not firing the AR.context.onLocationChanged"-JS-function call. 
what would be the problem?

Comment: Please have a look at the SDK sample application. Maybe you're firing the event too early in native code so your function is not yet set up in JS context.